# Update multiple rows and insert new from another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert, insert-update

i am new to this and i'll try to explain it as simple as i can.
i have two tables. profiles and loyalty profiles.

let's say that the table profiles has 10 rows and each profile created by a user is getting automatically a specific id.

These profiles and id's are already uploaded on loyalty profiles.

I now create a new profile on loyalty profiles and make some changes on some existing profiles.

Then the loyalty profiles should insert a new line in profiles table but having in mind the last id created in profiles table (because users are creating profiles on the system) and then update the existing profiles with any changes made from loyalty profiles by checking the id.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far? Insert triggers and update triggers might be able to solve this.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?